# How to programmatically avoid iPhone/iPad addition of a '.' char into textfields when typing 2 consecutive spaces?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield, autocorrect

When I type two or more consecutive space chars into an iPhone/iPad textfield, iOS adds a '.' char at the end of the last typed word, which is something I don't usually want. 
I think I've disabled all kind of "automatic correction controls" for my textfields inside Interface Builder, but no luck.

Comment: It's a user setting which you can disable for your own device. If at all possible to prevent it programmatically, it should be done using the UITextFieldDelegate method `shouldReplaceCharactersInRange:withString:`

Answer (score 1):

In this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)
```

instead of return YES
 do this:

```
return !(range.location > 0 && 
             [string length] > 0 &&
             [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]] &&
             [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[textField text] characterAtIndex:range.location - 1]]);

}
```